# Unrecognized variable after $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm with problem when I try to invoque an variable in javascript. For example:

```
listItem = "Hello";
listItem +=" Everyone";
```

Then I do this:

```
 $.post('example.php',{}, function(data){
          listItem += data;
    });
 alert(listItem);
```

The output is: Hello Everyone, but I wanted to concatenate with variable data. How I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this pattern instead of the callback, you'll be more likely to see what's going on:

```
$.post('example.php', {})
   .then(function(data)
   {
      //things inside this function execute after the post is done
      alert("Server has just replied to post.");
      listItem += data;
      alert(listItem);
   });
alert("Post was just sent.");
```

Your pop-ups will appear in this order:

- **[** Post was just sent. **]**
- **[** Server has just replied to post. **]**
- **[** contents of `listItem` **]**

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is asynchronous, so calling the alert right after the `$.post` call will print out the original array.

If you want to get the data, move the alert call in the success function or refactor your code in an asynchronous way.

Answer (score 0):

The order your code is run is this;

```
// 1.
listItem = "Hello";
listItem += " Everyone";

// 2.
alert(listItem);

// 3.
$.post('example.php', {}, /* your callback here */);

// 4. wait for server to respond

// 5. server responds

// 6. your call back is run
listItem += data;
```